# Expense Sharing api using DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, expense-splitting

I am creating an API which user can add expense in group. Imagine that we have 3 user in a group. User 1 add two expense with amount 90 and 210, and user 3 add an expense with amount 30. So basically when i see the group as User 1 i only should see Who do I owe and who owes me. it means i should see ( User2 owes you 100 and User3 owes you 90 ).
first problem is i dont know how to calculate the 90 because user 3 had expense with amount 30 it means user3 owes user 1 100 but with the expense he paid, it will reduce his part from his balance.

my main problem is in calculate settlements between 2 users amoung group.

```
class GroupRetrieveView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    
    
    def calculate_balance(self, pk):
        try:
            group = Group.objects.get(pk = pk)
        except group.DoesNotExists:
            return Response({'Error':'Group not found !'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        
        expenses = Expense.objects.filter(group = group)
        summary = defaultdict(Decimal)
        
        for expense in expenses:
            payer = expense.paid_by.username
            participants = expense.group.members.all()
            amount = Decimal(expense.amount)
            
            len_participants = participants.count()
            if len_participants > 0:
                # payment = amount - share
                share = amount / len_participants
                for participant in participants:
                    summary[participant.username] -= share
                
                summary[payer] += amount
                
        return summary
    
   
   
    def calculate_settlements(self, pk, user):
        try:
            group = Group.objects.get(pk = pk)
        except group.DoesNotExists:
            return Response({'Error':'Group not found !'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        
        
        settlements = defaultdict(Decimal)
        
        len_participants = group.members.count()
        
        expenses = Expense.objects.filter(group = group)
        
        totalpaid_summary = self.total_paid2(pk)
        
        for key, value in totalpaid_summary.items():
            if user.username != key:
                if value > 0:
                    bid = value / len_participants
                    settlements[key] = bid
                
            else:
                if value > 0:
                    bid = value / len_participants
                    settlements['you'] = bid
                
        return settlements
        
            
    def track_expense(self, pk):
        try:
            group = Group.objects.get(pk = pk)
        except group.DoesNotExists:
            return Response({'Error':'Group not found !'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        
        expenses = Expense.objects.filter(group = group)
        tracking = []
        s = self.calculate_balance(pk)
        
        
        for expense in expenses:
            payer = expense.paid_by.username
            amount = Decimal(expense.amount)
            participants = expense.group.members.all()
            
            
            len_participants = participants.count()
            if len_participants > 0:
                share = amount / len_participants
                payer_part = amount - share
                
            
            if payer == self.request.user.username:
                tracking.append(f'you paid {expense.amount} for {expense} , +{payer_part}')
                # tracking.append({f'{payer}':f'{payer_part}'})
            else:
                tracking.append(f'{payer} paid {expense.amount} for {expense}, -{share}')
            
        return tracking
    
    
    def total_paid(self, pk, user):
        try:
            group = Group.objects.get(pk = pk)
        except group.DoesNotExists:
            return Response({'Error':'Group not found !'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        
        expenses = Expense.objects.filter(group = group)
        
        total_paid = 0
        
        for expense in expenses:
            if expense.paid_by.username == user.username:
                total_paid += expense.amount
        
        return total_paid
            
            
    def total_paid2(self, pk):
        try:
            group = Group.objects.get(pk = pk)
        except group.DoesNotExists:
            return Response({'Error':'Group not found !'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        
        expenses = Expense.objects.filter(group = group)

        total_paid = defaultdict(Decimal)
        
        participants = group.members.all()
        participants_length = participants.count()
        
        
        for participant in participants:
            total_paid[participant.username]
            
        for expense in expenses:
            for key, value in total_paid.items():
                if key == expense.paid_by.username:
                    total_paid[key] += expense.amount
                                 
        return total_paid
        # return paid_amount
```